# Combine Image and Audio AND fade in and out

Tags: ffmpeg

I have an ffmpeg command that merges 1 image and 1 audio file, but I also want the output video to have a fade in and fade out, how can I do that?

Here's the command: `ffmpeg -r 1 -loop 1 -i images/image0.jpg -i audio.mp3 -acodec copy -r 1 -shortest -vf scale=1920:1080 final.mp4`